# Error from CMD running R statement and R file

Tags: r, cmd

I am trying to run R script and statement in win10 CMD with the following lines:

```
D:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.2\bin>r CMD BATCH E:\R scripts\AlgoTraining0101.R
D:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.2\bin>Rscript -e "library(C50)"
```

*E:\R scripts\AlgoTraining0101.R* is a R script file I created. 
I get an error:

> 'D:\Program' this is not an internal or external command, or batch
>   file...

When I run this

```
D:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.2\bin>Rscript -e "C50Training<-read.csv(file="E:/algo/dataset/C50Training.csv",header=TRUE)"
```

it says 'The system cannot find the file'.

The R command lines obviously had no problem in R studio but it does not work out in CMD. Can anyone help? I have searched but havent found anyone encourtering the same issue.

Thanks
[image]

Comment: You have spaces in the directory names. You have to quote them because spaces are also separators for the parts of the command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a best practice to quote paths and file names. This should be done whether they need it or not today. Someday they might. It also prevents frustration if it is a habit.

The error message is complaining that `C:\Program` cannot be found.

```
"D:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.2\bin\r" CMD BATCH "E:\R scripts\AlgoTraining0101.R"
"D:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.2\bin>Rscript" -e "library(C50)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running it with quotation marks, e.g.

```
"R" CMD BATCH "path/to/script.R"
# if R is has not been added to PATH
"path/to/R/R-x.y.z/bin" CMD BATCH "path/to/script.R"
```

I usually save the above as `.bat` file and am good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this with quote

```
D:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.2\bin\x64>R CMD BATCH "E:\R scripts\AlgoTraining0101.R"
```

It still gave me the error message 'E:\R' is not recognized as anything that the system understands. Then I changed the folder name from 'R scripts' to 'R_scripts' and ran this.

```
D:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.2\bin\x64>R CMD BATCH "E:\R_scripts\AlgoTraining0101.R"
```

It went through...So the quotation marks did not help here.